# What is a good solution for annotating javascript for static type checking?

Tags: javascript, types, static-analysis

what is a good solution for annotating javascript for static type checking?

Personally I have experience with TypeScript, and I like it, but the problem is that it has an overhead: If you want to work with others, either they learn TypeScript, or you downgrade to plain untyped Javascript.
I know jsdoc and the closure compiler, possibly others can statically typecheck javascript based on declarations in comment blocks. What is a suggested solution today?
Also, the typechecking should be over module boundaries as well (I am referring require(...) and pals)

Thank You!

Edit: It would be a plus, if variables could be annotated as constant. Even better, if the objects themselves could be annotated as immutable, but I realize that I am asking too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Flow now supports putting type annotations within block comments, so the source javascript is still valid javascript.  See here: http://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/20/Flow-Comments.html

Answer (score 1):

Facebook recently released [Flow](http://flowtype.org/), a static type-checker for JavaScript. This seems like it might fit what you're looking for.

Comment: Nice, but from what I've seen on it's official homepage, it suffers the same 'overhead' as TypeScript, although a lesser extent as type annotated flow code is not valid js,